# How to Make a <div> a Group of Items with VoiceOver on iPhone?

Tags: html, iphone, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I am attempting to create an accessible reading application using React. I aim to provide users with the ability to navigate between chapters easily while reading. To achieve this, I've used <div> elements to wrap the text content.

**like this:**

```
<div>
    <button>previous</button>
    <div aria-label='content'>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
        <p>paragraph 2</p>
        ...
        (many <p> tags)
    </div>
    <button>next</button>
<div>
```

When using the VoiceOver feature on my Mac, I can select the <div> element when choosing the "previous" button and press the "→" to navigate into the div, then use "Caps Lock + Shift + ↓" to enter the group. However, when performing the same action on the iPhone's browser, the selection only select the <p> tags.

I've attempted adjustments to the aria attributes and role attributes, but I haven't been able to replicate the behavior I experienced on the Mac.

Is there a way to modify the behavior of the <div> element on the iPhone to match the behavior I observed on the Mac?

on  [mac chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfPhp.png)

on [iphone safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZn6U.jpg)

Comment: VoiceOver on the Mac is quite different than on the iPhone, although if you enable the Trackpad Commander on your Mac, you can do iPhone gestures on the trackpad. I'm not following what behavior you want. You can't navigate to the outer <div> itself. It's not a semantic element. Also, the `aria-label` on your inner <div> will be ignored since the <div> doesn't have a role. See the 3rd last bullet point on https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support.